# Alamofire and SwiftyJSON getting value

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

I would like to use alamofire and swiftyjson to access my status: 101.
I need to be able to get the 101 and the message of "wrong login credential". Any ideas how I should do it?

```
▿ Optional<Any>
▿ some : 2 elements
▿ 0 : 2 elements
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : statusCode
    - value : 0
  ▿ 1 : 2 elements
    - key : statusDescription
    - value : Success!!
▿ 1 : 1 element
  ▿ 0 : 2 elements
    - key : user
    - value : {"status":"101","message":"wrong login credential"}
```

if I print my response, this shows:

```
    (
        {
        statusCode = 0;
        statusDescription = "Success!!";
    },
        {
        user = "{\"status\":\"101\",\"message\":\"wrong login credential\"}";
    }
)
```

I tried to use

```
let json = JSON(response.result.value as Any)

            let status = json["user"]["status"].string

            print(status)
```

but this doesnt work

Comment: Can you show the actual json that you are getting instead of the output from `print`?

Comment: the result i get is nil...no values...

Comment: No, I mean the actual json that the server is giving you. Do you know what that is?

Comment: I'd tend to say that `json["user"]` is a String, a JSONStringified, and you need to call again SwiftyJSON on it (might need to transform it into `(NS)Data` before, I don't know how works SwiftyJSON. But could you give us `response.result.stringValue` (or something like that, don't remember how it's done in Alamofire) or `let jsonString = String(data: response.result.value, encoding: .utf8)`

Comment: i am actually calling it from an API, the result from my response is the above output...

Comment: pls print your response and insert in your question

Comment: @IOS have edited and inserted my response

Comment: As I guessed, it's JSON Stringified within JSON: `let user: JSON(json["user"].string.data(encoding: .utf8)); let status = user["status"].string` should do the trick.

Comment: @Larme error of "Value of type 'JSON' has no member 'data'" will show

Comment: Edited my previous comment. I'm not a user of SwiftyJSON, forgot that part

Comment: @Larme couldnt get the status, it shows NIL...sorry guys to be bothering everyone. Couldnt get the value

Comment: If you confirm the `json` is not nil in `let json = ...`, try `let status = json["user"]["status"].stringValue`

Comment: this is not a valid json you can check with https://jsonlint.com

Comment: @zombie any way I could still get the value of 'status' or 'message' with this given condition?

Comment: @zombie That's a JSON already parsed (translated) into Dictionary/Array in Objective-C/Swift. Seems valid to me.